# How can I access a clickable textview in Java code?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I would like to access a clickable textview in my Java Code, to make it act like a hyperlink or `<a>` in html.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/signUp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginBtn"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.424" />
```

The above is my XML of the textview.

Comment: @rajan.kali please don't abuse code formatting like that. Inline code is NOT meant for names or highlighting stuff

Answer (score -1):

You can save your TextView in a variable, I've also changed it's text.

```
TextView register = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register);
register.setText("newText");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will check it out and comment back if it solved my problem. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can use setOnClickListener

```
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.registrar);
    textView.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){
            @Override
            void onclick(View v){
                   // body 
}
});
```